# Can I use screen pages without calling interrupts?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-mapping, video-memory

I searching for low level way to use screen pages without calling interrupts like sending characters directly to the video buffer without interrupts. Something instead the next code:

```
; Page 1
    mov     ax, 0501h
    int     10h
```

Comment: What graphics card are you programming for?  It is certainly possible to program an MDA or CGA card manually if you want.

Comment: I am talking for example for the normal text-mode screen 80*25

Comment: You have to read up on the [CRTC registers](https://cs.nyu.edu/~mwalfish/classes/14fa/ref/hardware/vgadoc/EGAREGS.TXT) and setting the start address. This is a EXE program for DOS (in MASM/TASM/JWASM syntax) that demonstrates this for CGA/EGA/VGA text video modes: https://pastebin.com/raw/mrig9vZn . Once the program exits type `cls` and hit enter to switch back to the page DOS was writing to.

Comment: A good reference for accessing the video hardware can be found here: http://www.osdever.net/FreeVGA/vga/vga.htm#register . If you are new to assembly and video hardware this may seem complex.